# sales_order_place_before event redirect

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I would like on the event `sales_order_place_before` to make some custom verification and to cancel the placing of the order.
What i have tried:

```
public function saleOrderPlaceBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
      if(!VerificationSuccess()){
            RemoveProduct();
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Product has expired.'));
            //how to redirect after error?
      }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the product is removed from the cart, but the error is shown as an alert box and i would like to redirect the user to some custom page.

After this, i tried directly to redirect to a custom page with something like:

```
 public function saleOrderPlaceBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
          if(!VerificationSuccess()){
                RemoveProduct();
                $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');      
                 $session->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__("Product expired!"));
                 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('product-error'));
                 Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
                 exit;
          }
    }
```

Using this code, i receive the error:

```
User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in PathToMagento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 4039
```

Any ideas on how to manage to cancel the placing of the order, remove the expired product and redirect from this observer(i can use other events also) to a custom page?

Comment: Hello @avi, I'm also want to redirect from `sales_order_place_before` to cart page if some custom condition match, How to do that?

Comment: sorry to disappoint you but, if i remember correctly, after a few days of searching for a solution that will not modify the core of magento, that requirement was dropped due to the lack of support from the magento community

Comment: No problem, Thanks for reply.